# Codeigniter - white strape while getting value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with CodeIgniter: 
A white strip appears on the top of the website while transfering values between pages. You can see it here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9BR3.png

I deleted all styles but it didn't solve the problem. 
I think that my configuration in CodeIgniter could be wrong, but I don't know what I can change.

Have you ever seen something like this?

Comment: what do you mean by  "my configuration in Codeingiter can be wrong" ?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

it is your browser default padding margin problem . in your css file use

```
*{
padding : 0;
margin:0;
}
```

your problem will be solve

Answer (score 0):

Your CI-Configuration is not wrong, but the image itself have a white space of visible height..that is why no css apply on it..

But you can do it using

.your_image {
 background-position : pos1 pos2;

}

Hope it would help u..